# Deleting pointers that point to the same variable

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

The code below is a condensed version of a code extract from a book, the idea was to create a copy of the **ptr** variable, then have the **ptr** variable point to a different address and finally delete the temporary pointer.

If my understanding is correct, does calling delete on the temporary pointer actually delete the original **num** variable? And since both the temporary pointer and **num** are dangling pointers is it correct to set them both to NULL?

```
int *num = new int(5);
int num1 = 10;

int *ptr = num;
int *temp = ptr;

ptr = &num1;

delete temp;
temp = NULL;
num = NULL;
```

Comment: Your code is correct. `delete` deletes the object being pointed to  (it's not a reference-counted release based on the pointer, or anything like that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: the one thing you allocated gets deleted.  I'm not sure what you mean by it being *correct* to assign NULL to variables, but in as much as their values before doing so no longer point to allocated memory, it certainly isn't a *bad* idea.

Answer (score 1):

> If my understanding is correct, **does calling delete on the temporary pointer actually delete the original num variable?** And since both the temporary pointer and num are dangling pointers is it correct to set them both to NULL?

Yes, because `ptr` & `num` point to exactly the same allocated memory address and the `delete` operator just needs that address, it doesn't care which variable holds that address.

> And **since both the temporary pointer and num are dangling pointers is it correct to set them both to NULL**?

It's not needed to set them to `NULL` (use `nullptr` if you are using C++11). But if you end up using those dangling pointers by mistake later, with a debugger it's a lot easier to catch the problem if the pointers are set to `nullptr`.